# What does Windows mean by a device that is "on the device path for a special file (such as the paging file, hibernate file, or crash dump file)"?

Tags: windows, device-driver

I noticed if you are [processing an IRP_MN_QUERY_DEVICE_RELATIONS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551670(v=vs.85).aspx) with a PowerRelations type and you add a power relation you are supposed to then send IRP_MN_DEVICE_USAGE_NOTIFICATION IRPs your device receives to the target device

> If the target device is on the device path for a special file (such
>   as the paging file, hibernate file, or crash dump file)...

I have not seen that wording before and have not had much luck googling it. Following the link for [IRP_MN_DEVICE_USAGE_NOTIFICATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550841(v=vs.85).aspx) it explains a bit more but not much details on what it actually is to have a special file attached to your device.

> System components send this IRP to ask the drivers for a device
>   whether the device can support a special file. Special files include
>   paging files, dump files, and hibernation files. If all the drivers
>   for the device succeed the IRP, the system creates the special file.

What does it mean to be on the device path for a special file and what sorts of devices typically are?

Comment: It is sent by *system components*.  You are not writing a driver that implements a system component.  It is otherwise a power management micro-optimization, turns macro when the battery runs out.

Comment: @HansPassant: while the snippet in the question doesn't make it clear, the documentation describes conditions under which third-party drivers have to send this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the control code in question.**

However, the meaning of the documentation seems clear enough.

Consider the paging file, for example, which is typically `C:\pagefile.sys`.  From the kernel's point of view, that's

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume1\pagefile.sys
```

Which makes `Device\HarddiskVolume1` a device that is "on the device path to a special file".  Reading the documentation, the rules in question also apply to any other device that this device depends upon.

In practical terms, you only need to worry about this if you're a storage device of some kind, or a bus device that supports storage devices.  If this applies to you, and if you support special files (i.e., return success when you receive `IRP_MN_DEVICE_USAGE_NOTIFICATION` with `InPath` set to `TRUE`) *and* if you have a non-trivial power dependency on another device, then you have to forward the IRP as described.

If you don't need to support special files, you can just fail the call.  There's probably no need to support special files on a removable media device, for example, so USB controllers, hubs, etc., probably don't support them.  But a RAID controller probably *does* need to support special files, at least if you want to be able to install Windows on the RAID disk.